# Shopify: tagging customers after purchasing certain products

Tags: shopify

Is there a way to automatically tag a customer after they purchased a product?

For instance, if a customer buys product A, they will be automatically tagged "A" or something?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is easily done with a custom App. Your App will listen for orders. When an order comes in, it will inspect the order for the products purchased. It can then write the appropriate tags into the customers file.

Comment: is it through webhooks or is there another method? I'm trying to use rails to create an app. I'm going through the examples, which it shows products and orders. I'm trying to find out what class I need to use to capture the object when user clicks buy... or is my logic completely off?

Comment: Setup a Webhook for orders/paid. That approach has nothing to do with live customers using the shop. On the other hand is client-side code. You can try using Ajax to modify the logged in customer. Whatever turns your crank. I have done both and both work fine.